# How to remove an email which is stuck in the outbox of the Windows 8 Mail app

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-messaging-app

It's already the second time, I have an E-Mail in the outbox of the Mail-app of Windows 8 which is stuck. I don't see the exact reason why this happens (I have no big files attached to the mails and the recipient is valid).

The first time I have had this problem, I have not found a simple way to remove the stucked email. I solved the Problem by removing the accounts from the mail app and then adding the same accounts newly to the app. However I'm wondering if there is a more simple way of doing this?

Does someone know how to remove an email which is stuck in the outbox?

Comment: [You are not alone](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/Windows-8-metro-mail-app-outbox-is-stuck)

Comment: Just sync it again. The message will be sent. Or disconnect from the internet and reconnect.

Comment: @Pratyush Nalam: No, this does not solve the problem. But thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "simpler" way. The fix:

- Disable your network interface(s) (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, type "view network connections" and press Enter, right-click and **Disable** your network connection)
- Open the Mail app and go to the Outbox
- There is now a delete icon in the top right for each stuck mail item !
- Don't forget to enable your connection(s) again

Also another option is:

- Go to your desktop
- Right-click on your wireless in the System Tray
- Go to **Open Network and Sharing Center**
- Go to **View Network Connections** (on the left)
- Disable from there and then follow step 2 above

Comment: +1 Wow! How did you find this? Great!

Comment: I'd love to say I figured it out myself but I actually found this answer here (last post in the thread) : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-winapps/mail-stuck-on-outbox-on-windows-8-release-preview/760636a2-dd9e-4d94-a9fa-ef6befc66ae4 !

Answer (score 0):

I had a number of emails stuck in my outbox, along with an inability to sync email in general.

Restarting the system fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, this has not helped on my system.

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of the mail app, I was able to solve another similar problem by going into the accounts settings tab of the email-app, selecting the problematic account and disabled there the synchronization of email. 
After disabling it, I waited a while to let the app affect the changes, terminated the app, restarted the computer, and then re-enabled the email-synchronization.

Maybe this helps another person as well.